# non-positive roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Consider the even polynomial
$$
\Phi(z)=a_6z^6+a_4z^4+a_2z^2+a_0=0\;,
$$
where $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$. Given that $a_0<0$ and $a_6>0$, does there exist conditions to guarantee that $\Phi$ has no positive real roots? This seems impossible, but maybe I'm missing something! What I would prefer are good references on this type of problem, or ideas to work with.

Comment: If $z_0$ is a root then $-z_0$ is also a root, so you want all roots of $\phi$ to be non-real.

Comment: Good point. How would you ensure that all the real parts of such roots are in the left half-plane?

Comment: The same argument applies, it can only be possible if all the roots are pure imaginary.

Answer (score 3):

Observe $\Phi(0) = a_0 <0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \Phi(t) = \infty.$ Hence, by the intermediate value theorem $\Phi$ has a positive root.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the intermediate value theorem stuff. I guess I was hoping one could get a condition (on the coefficients) that somehow negates what you just said; for example, if the relative minimum value of $\Phi$ (at the positive root) is strictly positive. It would really be useful to me if this were possible...

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the complex roots of $\Phi$ come in conjugate pairs
because $\Phi(\overline{z})=\overline{\Phi(z)}$.
Therefore, if $\Phi$ has no real roots then it can be written
as
$\Phi(z) = a_6(z-u)(z-\overline{u})(z-v)(z-\overline{v})(z-w)(z-\overline{w})$
for (possibly duplicate) complex numbers $u,v,w$ and you will
have $a_0 = \Phi(0) = a_6 |u|^2 |v|^2 |w|^2$. But this would only be possible
if $a_6$ and $a_0$ had the same sign.

Of course, as already answered, the intermediate value theorem is a quicker
way to see this.